# How to point to initial runtime when restarting an existing docker container

Tags: linux, docker, cuda, nvidia, nvidia-docker

I would like to restart a docker container, after exiting it and rebooting, with the same runtime with which it was initially created.

Here's what I did so far.

Create the container:

```
sudo docker run --runtime=nvidia [...]
```

Restart Docker after exiting the container and rebooting:

```
service docker restart
```

Restart the container previously created:

```
sudo docker start my_container
```

Reopen the container.

```
docker exec -it my_container [...]
```

The program which is then launched in the container doesn't use the Nvidia GPU as expected. It instead uses the system CPU.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by same runtime? DO you mean you need your docker container to be running on system reboot/startup or even on docker service restart?

Comment: I'd like the nvidia GPU to be used when commands are run in the restarted container.

Comment: You mean the `--runtime=nvidia` option of docker run should always work and point to nvidia runtime?

Comment: Not always, only for the specific container that was created using the `--runtime=nvidia` option. There's probably a concept I'm missing about Docker, but when I first create the container (with the `run` command) the program I launch within it executes using the nvidia GPU, which is not the case when I exit the container then reopen it with the `exec` command.

Comment: It happens that the problem occurs only on system reboot. If I simply `stop` the container then `start` it again, the nvidia GPU is sill used. I would guess the runtime is unregistered on reboot.

Comment: in your docker run command make use of `--restart=always` option. Give it a try and let me know, if it works on reboot with correct runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the expected result by creating a new container with the `--restart=unless-stopped` policy, which lets Docker restart the container by itself when the Docker service is restarted. There seems to be more that's being done in this process than the `start`/`exec` sequence that I was using.